# ViewController content size doesn't change popover size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

The popover's preferred size is only works if the height is greater than 320.

I have searched a lot to solve this issue. But didn't find any answer. Is there any minimum size that the popover should satisfy in iPad? If not, what i'm missing?

**Code:**

```
UIViewController *viewController = [subStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:SMFormViewControllerSBID];
controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

SMFormViewController *formViewController = (SMFormViewController *)controller.topViewController;
formViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
formViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 320);

popController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft;
popController.delegate = self;

popController.sourceView = tblDocDetails;
NSInteger section = [tblDocDetails numberOfSections] - 1;
CGRect rectCustomLoc = [tblDocDetails rectForFooterInSection:section];
popController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(rectCustomLoc.origin.x, rectCustomLoc.origin.y, 130, rectCustomLoc.origin.y/2);

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

***Note:***
I tried, `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:` & `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:` to return `UIModalPresentationNone`.

Comment: Have you tried adding `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` in SMFormViewController.m ?

Comment: i just tried, and its not working. @Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My popover sometimes doesn't visible, because of the `sourceRect` was incorrect.

Since I embedded ViewController in a Navigation Controller, `preferredContentSize` should set to Navigation Controller.

```
controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 100);
```

& in **ViewController:**

```
self.navigationController.preferredContentSize = contentsize;
```

And Changed `sourceRect` to:

```
CGRect rectCustomLoc = [table rectForFooterInSection:section];
rectCustomLoc.size.width = sender.frame.size.width;
popController.sourceRect = rectCustomLoc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIButton *btnOpen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnOpen setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 44)];
    [btnOpen setTitle:@"POP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnOpen setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [btnOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(btnOpen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnOpen];
}

- (void)btnOpen:(id)sender {
    UIView *sourceView = (UIButton *)sender;

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 150);
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popVc = vc.popoverPresentationController;
    popVc.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft;
    popVc.sourceView = sourceView;
    popVc.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds;
}
```

and it resulted in this (iPad Air 2, iOS 11.2):

[image: 150x150 popover]

Here is a solution based on your example, I think your use of GCD to show the popover might be causing the issue...

```
    UIViewController *viewController = [subStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:SMFormViewControllerSBID];
    controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 320);

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    popController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft;
    popController.delegate = self;

    popController.sourceView = tblDocDetails;
    NSInteger section = [tblDocDetails numberOfSections] - 1;
    CGRect rectCustomLoc = [tblDocDetails rectForFooterInSection:section];
    popController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(rectCustomLoc.origin.x, rectCustomLoc.origin.y, 130, rectCustomLoc.origin.y/2);
```

Comment: @LalKrishna I think I've found your problem. The issue is that you set the "preferredContentSize" and "modalPresentationStyle" on "formViewController" instead of "controller". Since "controller" is the top-most viewcontroller - the size and presentation style should be set on it.

Comment: i tried setting, `controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;` too. & it's still Not Working.

Comment: @LalKrishna I will post an alternative solution that you can try in a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166295/discussion-between-lal-krishna-and-emmanuel-ay).

Comment: My popover sometimes doesn't visible, because of the `sourceRect` was incorrect. So `controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 100);` doesn't make change to popover size. Anyway I voted up for you found that `preferredContentSize` to the navigation controller. Thanks!